# Order list items after first whitespace and then same words

Tags: python, sorting

I have the following sample list in python:

```
test_list = ['ViewData.Accounting Base Net Amount',
'ViewData.Accounting Cancel Amount',
 'ViewData.Accounting Cancel Flag',
 'ViewData.Accounting OTE Custodian Account',
 'ViewData.Accounting OTE Ticker',
 'ViewData.Accounting OTEIncludeFlag',
 'ViewData.Accounting Principal Amount',
 'ViewData.Accounting Trade Date',
 'ViewData.Accounting Trade Expenses',
 'ViewData.B-P Base Net Amount',
 'ViewData.B-P Cancel Amount',
 'ViewData.B-P Cancel Flag',
 'ViewData.B-P OTE Custodian Account',
 'ViewData.B-P OTE Ticker',
 'ViewData.B-P OTEIncludeFlag',
 'ViewData.B-P Principal Amount',
 'ViewData.B-P Trade Date',
 'ViewData.B-P Trade Expenses']
```

I am trying to arrange this list such that the list looks like this

```
    test_list = ['ViewData.Accounting Base Net Amount',
    'ViewData.B-P Base Net Amount',
    'ViewData.Accounting Cancel Amount',
    'ViewData.B-P Cancel Amount',
     'ViewData.Accounting Cancel Flag',
     'ViewData.B-P Cancel Flag',
     'ViewData.Accounting OTE Custodian Account',
     'ViewData.B-P OTE Custodian Account',
     'ViewData.Accounting OTE Ticker',
     'ViewData.B-P OTE Ticker',
     'ViewData.Accounting OTEIncludeFlag',
     'ViewData.B-P OTEIncludeFlag',
     'ViewData.Accounting Principal Amount',
     'ViewData.B-P Principal Amount',
     'ViewData.Accounting Trade Date',
     'ViewData.B-P Trade Date',
     'ViewData.Accounting Trade Expenses',
     'ViewData.B-P Trade Expenses']
```

What I have done till now is split the list elements after the first whitespace and then order them like this:

```
sorted(test_list, key=lambda x: x.split()[1])
```

The output for this is as follows:

```
['ViewData.Accounting Base Net Amount',
 'ViewData.B-P Base Net Amount',
 'ViewData.Accounting Cancel Amount',
 'ViewData.Accounting Cancel Flag',
 'ViewData.B-P Cancel Amount',
 'ViewData.B-P Cancel Flag',
 'ViewData.Accounting OTE Custodian Account',
 'ViewData.Accounting OTE Ticker',
 'ViewData.B-P OTE Custodian Account',
 'ViewData.B-P OTE Ticker',
 'ViewData.Accounting OTEIncludeFlag',
 'ViewData.B-P OTEIncludeFlag',
 'ViewData.Accounting Principal Amount',
 'ViewData.B-P Principal Amount',
 'ViewData.Accounting Trade Date',
 'ViewData.Accounting Trade Expenses',
 'ViewData.B-P Trade Date',
 'ViewData.B-P Trade Expenses']
```

But this doesn't give me the desired output cause elements coming after the second whitespace are grouped together, which is not what I want. Is there a way to arrange similar word combinations after the first whitespace together

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `split` is the number of times to split the string, if you pass `1` it will split the string in 2 (unless the separator is not present)

```
>>> 'ViewData.Accounting Base Net Amount'.split(' ', 1)
['ViewData.Accounting', 'Base Net Amount']
```

You want to order by the rest of the string after the first space, you can order by the 2nd element of the split call using this

```
sorted(test_list, key=lambda x: x.split(' ', 1)[1])
```

Comment: Oh nice. That made sense. This worked. Thanks for the quick response.